# Disabling hyper-v in windows 8.1 does not work system rolls back changes

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, hyper-v

```
I have installed the android studio and learnt that you need to enable 
virtualization in the bios and disable hyper-v under turn windowsfeatures on and off.
```

Here is the problem : After turning the hyper-v off the system requires a restart but mine doesnt complete
     the changes instead it rols back changes with an error that windows could not
     complete the changes

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here. I'll try to find out why you can't disable hyper-V.

Comment: have you uploaded the logs?